# how do I create a series of similar html objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I need to create about 20 flip card elements in a site, and I don't want to write them down one by one. Is there a way, using JavaScript classes, to display various objects with each different parameters (such as photos and statuses) in an html page? The code I have now is this:

```html
<div id = "flipcard" class = "type1 product1" >
<div id = "fcfront"> 
<img class = "img" src = "../dir/file.png" alt = "Product 1"
<p class = "avaiable">Avaiable</p>
<form action = "mail@gmail.com">
<input type = "text" placeholder = "Insert Phone Number">
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
<form>
</div>
<div id = "fcback">
<p>*info*</p>
</div> 
</div>
```

then I have the css file with the classes and colors already set and :hover thingy to flip the actual card. Now I need to have this over and over again changing the "avaiable" class to "unavaiable", change the src value of each img element and the type1 and product1 class in the first value. Help me please

Comment: Create an array of object with all value you need to use a simple forEach with innerHTML.

Comment: the img tag in your snippet is not closed, btw

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes, but then you will need to implement object state and a render system (like React). A simpler method might be to use a for-loop and render your elements as innerHTML of a container.

```js
const cards = document.querySelector('#cards');
for (let i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
  const card = `<div id="flipcard" class="type${i} product${i}">
      <div id="fcfront">
        <img class="img" src="../dir/file.png" alt="Product ${i}">
        <p class="avaiable">Avaiable</p>
        <form action="mail@gmail.com">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Phone Number">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          <form>
      </div>
      <div id="fcback">
        <p>*info*</p>
      </div>
    </div>`;
  cards.innerHTML += card; 
}
```

```html
<section id="cards"></section>
```